# Error while trying to open CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

Python rookie here. Trying to use the CSV module, but I get an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'books.csv'
```

The actual CSV file is stored on my desktop. I suppose this means Python can't find the file? If so, how can I fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Give it the full path to the file, or run the script in the same directory where the file is.

Comment: Are you specifying the absolute pathname of your csv file?

Comment: It never hurts to use raw strings while opening files: `fo = open(r'X:\Loc\To\File', 'r')` especially if you're using Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Since your file name includes no path component, it is implicitly assigned to be in the current directory. Unless your current directory is the desktop, you won't be able to find the file.

Either give it a full pathname, or move to the desktop and run your script from there.

Comment: Awesome! I simply moved the script to the desktop, and it works just fine. I had a feeling it the solution was very simple! Thanks guys!